# jQuery feature date disabled working fine but it was not working for my current code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Working on date picker using jquery I have two query with the date picker. With my current code I am getting the yearrange from 1900 to 2100 and  I can able to disabled the feature date means from (1900 - 2015 sep) it was disabled till this month end  but I was not able to see calendar till 2100.My second query was though user can see year till 2100 the field should accept only 10 years from today.

Here is the jquery code

```
$("#txt_dob").datepicker({
    dateFormat:"mm-dd-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange:'1900:2100',
    //maxDate:'date',
}).on('change', function() {
    if($('#txt_dob').valid()){
        $('#txt_dob').removeClass('errRed');
    }
// triggers the validation test on change
});
```

Any suggestion please help me

Updated JSBIN [Link](http://jsbin.com/tovutu/edit?html,js,output)

Here is the HTML CODE

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_dob" name="txt_dob" />
```

Comment: I would reccomend that you try to make your titles clearer in the future, you have a better chance of having someone who has your answer click on the question if they can understand the topic. :)

Comment: show us where it is working and where it is not